# how can i get the id of the image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i'm trying to get the id of the image using jquery

html:

```
  <div id="multiTemp" style="display:none">
   <div class="imgae">
   <div class="otimage">
  <img  id="**img**" **src=""**>
  </div>
  <ul>
  <li class="removeimg"><a href="#"><img src="removee.png"
   height="20" alt="delete" title="Delete"></a></li>
   <li  class=**unlikeImgs**" ><a href="#">
  <img src="unlike.PNG" height="20" /></a>
  </li>
   <li class="**likeImgs**" ><a href="#"><img 
  src="like.PNG" height="20" /></a>
   </li>

   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

this is the html, how can i get img id for class "img" if i click images with class likeImgs and unlikeImgs. I Tried but couldnt get it. any help please

jquery:

```
  $(this).parent().parent().children().first().attr('id');
```

Comment: 'I Tried but couldnt get it.' - *What* did you try?

Comment: What `id` do you want to get and where exactly do you click? I don't see any images having the classes you mention, nor do they have any ids...

Comment: images are in li ..and i want the img id with class "img". I've edited my question..is the way correct @Christoph

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('.imgae').each(function(){
       var holder = $(this),
           images = holder.find('img');

        images.each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('id')){
                console.log($(this).attr('id'), $(this).parent())
            }
        })
    });
});
```

You can try:

http://jsfiddle.net/NcNvu/12/

or other approach:

```
$(function() {
  console.log($('#multiTemp').find('img').attr('id'))
});
```

Comment: user doesn't want id of all the images in document.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").attr("id");
```

reference **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**